# Moto G5 plus, not vibrating on incoming calls

Tags: calls, motorola-moto-g, vibration, 8.1-oreo

I have Moto G5 Plus, with Android Version 8.1.0. This issue is related to vibration feature. My phone has stopped vibrating when I receive incoming calls. The phone vibrates properly when there is a SMS message. I have also checked the settings under Settings -> Sounds. The option "Also vibrate for calls" is turned on already. I have also restarted the phone several times, but the problem remains the same. Could anyone help me understand why the Vibration is not working for incoming calls when the vibration is working for SMS. I justed edited to mention that the key press is also not working. Vibration is also working when I shake the phone to switch on the torch light.

(DND not enabled)

Edit

I have observed one more behaviour. There are two ways, incoming calls are shown. Sometimes I see a box at the top with accept and decline square buttons. In this case I do not hear vibration. Sometimes, I see a full screen with a circle button at the bottom which I have to drag up to receive the call. In this case, I hear vibration just once at the beginning and then no vibration. So I am really confused as why does box appears sometimes and why circle button at the top and why vibration does not happen in the first case.